# debounceTime no work with search? Angular 9+

Tags: angular

I try to set debounce time in my search but no work... Check my code:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.search.valueChanges.subscribe(
      (selectedValue) => {
        this.searchVal(selectedValue)
      }
    );
  }

  private getAllDrivers(query: string) {
    console.log('gar')
    return this.accountsService.getDrivers(query)
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(800),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        map((data: any) => {
          data.body?.forEach((driver: IDriver) => {
            driver.name = `${driver.firstName} ${driver.lastName}`
          });
          return data.body || [];
        }),
        tap(() => noop, err => {
          this.errorMessage = err && err.message || 'Something goes wrong';
        })
      )
  }


public search: FormControl = new FormControl(null);
```

html:

```
 <input [formControl]="search">
```

Why not work this code?

when I'm looking for something every moment I get http get ...I need any delay for half seconds , seconds ...

I am also try with :

```
  this.search.valueChanges.
   .pipe(debounceTime(800))
    subscribe(
     (selectedValue) => {
    this.searchVal(selectedValue)
  }
);
```

also no work...

Answer (score 0):

You have to `debounceTime` and `switchMap` but you second example should work more or less as well.

Assuming that `this.search.valueChanges` is an user input changes observable

```
this.search.valueChanges.pipe(
   debounceTime(800),
   distinctUntilChanged(),
  switchMap(query=>this.accountsService.getDrivers(query))
).subscibe(results => do sometinh)
```